# Adding column value for a list of indexes

Tags: pandas, indexing

I have a list of indexes and trying to populate a column `'Type'` for these rows only.

What I tried to do:

```
index_list={1,5,9,10,13} 
df.loc[index_list,'Type']=="gain+loss"

Output:
1      False
5      False
9      False
10     False
13     False
```

But the output just gives the list with all False instead of populating these rows.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: `==` should be `=` ?

Comment: Thanks @Psidom, tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your dataframe, @Ran?

Comment: Please explain what's not working

Comment: Sorry guys for the late reply, It works now. I'm not sure what happened yesterday, but changing '==' to '=' solved the issue. Thank you! @Psidom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a single equal instead of double equal. In python, and in most progamming languages, == is the comparison operator. In your case you need the assignment operator =.
So the following code will do what you want :

```
index_list={1,5,9,10,13} 
df.loc[index_list,'Type']="gain+loss"
```